# How to use Java I/O to read file lines in a loop?

Tags: java

I am trying to write DenverSortedCities and I did print exist file and but I need to write a loop to continue reading while there is more information in the file.

As the loop cycle through all cities in the file, it will keep track of the **largest city** and its **population**. This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File inFile = new File("DenverSortedCities.txt");

    if (inFile.exists()){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);

        while(input.hasNextLine()){
            String cityInfo = input.nextLine();
            String[] cityInfoArray = cityInfo.split("0,1");

            int populationValue = Integer.parseInt(cityInfo);
        }
        System.out.println(input.nextLine());

        input.close();
    } else {
        System.out.println(inFile.getName() + " does not exist.");
        System.exit(1);

    }
}
```

Comment: after String cityInfo = input.nextLine(); and String [] cityInfoArry = cityInfo.split(","); I need to excute, cityInfoarray[0] will contain city name, and cityInfoArry[1] will contain the population.  i don't know how do i use this ...just comfused

Comment: what is the content of DenverSortedCities?

Comment: city name and pop number

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to do it assuming that your file is a `CSV` file with a comma as separator and the city name as first value and its population as second value:

```
// Use a try-with-resource statement to close the scanner once done
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile)) {
    String largestCity = null;
    int population = 0;
    long total = 0L;
    // Iterate as long as we have remaining lines in the file
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String cityInfo = input.nextLine();
        String[] cityInfoArray = cityInfo.split(",");
        // Convert the second value corresponding to the population to an Integer
        int populationValue = Integer.parseInt(cityInfoArray[1]);
        // Check if the current population is bigger than the current largest
        if (populationValue > population) {
            population = populationValue;
            largestCity = cityInfoArray[0];
        }
        total += populationValue;
    }
    // Print the result
    System.out.printf(
        "The largest city is '%s' with a population of %d inhabitants.%n", 
        largestCity, population
    );
    System.out.printf("The total population is %d.%n", total);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works and only display the largest city and number..... but it doesn't display the results of Total population

Comment: as a loop cycles through all cities in the file, it will keep track of the largest city and its population.

Comment: it wii also tally the total population